# Encoding error PHP and Mysql for french

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I have a function that adds words in my database and for some reason it's putting them in all weird.

Here is my function :

```
function change_team($picname, $text){
    include 'dbconnector.php';
    $conn->query("UPDATE team SET  tea_photo = '$picname', tea_text = $text WHERE tea_id = 1"); 
}
```

Then, I use a post form to put it in :

`change_team($_POST['lala'], $_POST['text']);`

`$_POST['text'] = éÀéÀ` works when I echo it before entering it into database, but in the database it does this: *Ã‰Ã Ã‰*

I've tried everything, I've put my table as uft8_general_ci but it doesn't seem like it fixes anything.

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 0):

In your `dbconnector.php`, do:

```
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
```

After connecting and selecting database. This will set the *transmission* encoding to UTF-8. (The table/column/db character set is just *storage* encoding).

Comment: Tried, doesnt solve my problem :(

Comment: If you are not at least seeing a different outcome, then you didn't apply it correctly somehow

Comment: The datas are perfect until it comes to entering it into the database, which I dont understand because I've done everything everybody is suggesting everywhere... it just doesnt seem to work out

Comment: In fact, it can print UTF8 really well, if I enter then in my database manualy using SQL, it just seem that this query doesnt works :

$conn->query("INSERT INTO categories VALUES(DEFAULT, '$name')");

any tought ?

Comment: @YannChabot I mean the command I suggested must at least give you different results. Where does `$name` come from?

Comment: its a variable in the function ! No, sadly its still the same results, in fact, the command makes an error with my server...

Comment: OMG ! Found it !! In fact, you're right ! It made it work out... I had to do UTF8_DECODE() then to make it work, double encoding maybe ?

Comment: @YannChabot I need to know where the data originates from. Is it literally typed in your php source file? Coming from browser POST? Coming from 3rd party web service? These all have different solutions.

Comment: @YannChabot no, never use utf8_decode.

Comment: Yes, its a function argument, $name is from a POST form

Comment: @YannChabot right. Then use `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");` to make browser send you forms in UTF-8. Get rid of any functions you have used trying to fix this (such as `utf8_decode`) and ensure you still have `$conn->set_charset("utf8");`